# Override only some of the generic variables

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following scenario:

```
class Test<A extends myObjectType = myObjectType, B extends myOtherObjectType = myOtherObjectType> {};

const TestValue: Test<myObjectType, myChangedObjectType> = ...
```

Is it possible somehow, to only override SOME of the generic variables which have a default value assigned to them?

What I would want to achieve, is the ability, to do something like this:

```
class SecondTest extends <_, myChangedObjectType> { ... }
```

and I would like Typescript to know, that by ommiting the first generic parameter (by providing to it a default value, for example _), I am referring to the the default value of the original class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a *later* type argument if you've left a previous type argument unspecified. Here's a link to the [2.3 docs on type parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) but I don't think it's changed (the v.4.4.4 playground won't let me do it).

So you could leave off the second type argument in your example (`Test<something>`), or both of them (`Test`), but you can't leave off just the first one while specifying the second (`Test</*nothing here*/, something>`).

Comment: Your answer is more correct, seems to be that OP wants to mutate created type

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Thanks. I thought they just wanted to define (basically) `const TestValue = Test<, myChangedObjectType>` but I think you've read the question differently. Hopefully the OP will clarify, because I honestly don't know whether I've read it right. :-)

Comment: updated my question. so I am left with either defining all generic types. wouldn't this have a valid use case? for example, if I have a type that uses a lot of generic predefined values?

Comment: you should either omit all of them or only last default generic

Comment: @AdamBaranyai - Put the required ones first, then the optional ones. But unfortunately, if you have (for instance) `interface Example<A, B, C = DefaultC, D = DefaultD>` and you want to specify a different D when using it, you have to specify `DefaultC` explicitly. (This is fairly common in things that allow default values, JavaScript's default parameter value thing allowing you to say `undefined` to get the default is very much atypical.) I don't think there's a way around this, but captain-yossarian is better at TypeScript than I am, so... I have to admit I don't understand his answer. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right, there is no `wild card`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have to admint, when I saw captain-yossarian's answer, I was thinking about closing off SO for the day:P

Comment: @AdamBaranyai  It's often worth persisting, because he really does know this stuff inside out. But I think he's answering a different question. You're not trying to *modify* `Test`, right? You're just trying to define it without having to specify `myObjectType` as the first generic argument?

Comment: AFAIK, in js you can use `undefined` and then if argument has default parameter it will use default parameter. `never`  type might be treated in some way as undefined type, or empty type but, once you provide it TS will use it

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Yup, that's what I was referring to above as JavaScript's slightly-atypical (but useful!) approach to default parameter values. If you have `function example(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) { return a + b + c; }` then `example()` and example(undefined, undefined, undefined)` both use the defaults and return 6.

Answer (score 2):

As @T.J.Crowder said, there is no way to mutate or override generic argument.

However there is a workaround. You can create new type which inherits first argument from previous type and add new generic type

```js
type myObjectType = {
  tag: 'myObjectType'
}
type myOtherObjectType = {
  tag: 'myOtherObjectType'
}

class Test<A extends myObjectType = myObjectType, B extends myOtherObjectType = myOtherObjectType> { };


type Change<
  Class extends Test<any, any>,
  NewType extends myOtherObjectType> =
  (Class extends Test<infer Type, infer _>
    ? (Type extends myObjectType
      ? Test<Type, NewType>
      : never)
    : never)

type Changed = Change<Test<myObjectType, myOtherObjectType>, myOtherObjectType & { greet: 'hello' }>;

declare var changed: Changed;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiDyAjAVhAxsAKuaBeKA3gFBRTACGA5gFxQDkcSqG2kdRAvkaJLAsAAsIAJybosOKPmKkKNeo0EixLHOy5E0AG3IBnXVEwRdwADwBBKBAAewCADsAJgcYpxrPHxUTIAGigAQla2Ds5eSqJuqrz4ikKRzD4QAHyEUBwA3ETZPNAAwgLk9pQQpiRQeTr6wXZOBkYmpkUg-s3JvuUAchAA7h41oS788d4eqbjlABSVegY2tWENZgCW9gBmIoY4-qsbwlAA+snlpAD8UJP984NeUUknpFDnS6Ye-t19OMePj7T2EAA3EQASgef0BIJykgKRRKjikFUKxVKL1ciTe4RGdzG-jiymxkgAZGlKMIIBBgLQ6EItFoAPZ0dLJLJERzoHRkqAA8j7NBIuG0GHIxwsoA)

You can infer only first generic type and construct new type with first generic type and new second generic type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, made an update

Comment: oh, so that means this would not solve my problem:( updated my question with an example