# Typescript avoid providing a parameter to a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Suppose I have some generic type

```
type Foo<T = string, U = number> = {
    t: T
    u: U
}
```

Neither T nor U are required. How can I provide U but not T.

Ideally I could do something like

```
type G = Foo<,string> //  expected syntax 
// expected result 
type G = {
    t: string;
    u: string;
}
```

Things I've tried:

```
type G = Foo<never, string> // ❌
type G = Foo<unknown, string> // ❌
type G = Foo<Foo['t'], string> // ❌ (Works in this exact example but not in the general case. I want to extract the first default parameter type rather than extracting out the resulting `t`).
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=13#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFSgXigZ2AJwJYB2A5gDQCq6UBArgLYBGEOAfJQN4BQU3UwAXFGRce1AWQ4BfDh1CQoRSvCQEIANyYksuQkWbTZ0ABaKEQA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override only some of the generic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660413/override-only-some-of-the-generic-variables)

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok having a `DefaultType` pre-hand defined and passing `null` as the "optional" first parameter, this could work:

```
type DefaultType = number;
type Foo<T, U = number> = T extends null ? {
    t: DefaultType
    u: U
} : {
    t: T
    u: U
}

type h = Foo<null,string>
const newVar:h = {
  t: 1,
  u: "123"
} 

type h1 = Foo<string,string>
const newVar1: h1 = {
  t: "string",
  u: "string"
}
```